# babel-preset-react-app not picking up environment variables

Tags: node.js, reactjs, babeljs, create-react-app

> Failed to compile ./src/index.js Module build failed: Error: Using
>   `babel-preset-react-app` requires that you specify `NODE_ENV` or
>   `BABEL_ENV` environment variables. Valid values are "development",
>   "test", and "production". Instead, received: "undefined". (While
>   processing
>   preset:"C:\Users\mitch\OneDrive\Development\Git\react-seed\node_modules\babel-preset-react-app\index.js")
>   at Array.map (native)

I keep getting the above error no matter how many weird and wonderful ways I try to set either the environment or the environment variables since updating my react-app and I even get this on a fresh app created from the 'create-react-app' scripts - What am I clearly doing wrong?

Answer (score 11):

I do it in my package.json:

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "build": "NODE_ENV=development babel src -d lib",
    "build-prod": "NODE_ENV=production babel src -d lib"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Using `babel-preset-react-app` requires that you specify `NODE_ENV` or `BABEL_ENV` environment variables. Valid values are "development", "test", and "production". Instead, received: "development "

Ran into a similar problem and noticed that a space character messed things up with this configuration:

```
SET NODE_ENV=development && node server/bootstrap.js

//Changed to this:
SET NODE_ENV=development&&node server/bootstrap.js
```

Answer (score -1):

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "build": "export NODE_ENV=development && babel src -d lib",
    "build-prod": "export NODE_ENV=production && babel src -d lib"
  }
}
```