# How to provide `babel-preset-react-app` env variables?

Tags: reactjs, express, redux, babeljs, create-react-app

I am working on an App which connects create-react-app with an express server( using server rendering). I am referring  [this tutorial](https://medium.com/bucharestjs/upgrading-a-create-react-app-project-to-a-ssr-code-splitting-setup-9da57df2040a) for it.To render the file from server, the code is

**bootstrap.js**

```
require('ignore-styles');
require('babel-register')({
ignore:[/(node-modules)/],
presets:['es2015','react-app']
});
require('./index');
```

**index.js**

```
import express from 'express';
// we'll talk about this in a minute:
import serverRenderer from './middleware/renderer';


const PORT = 3000;
const path = require('path');
// initialize the application and create the routes
const app = express();
const router = express.Router();
// root (/) should always serve our server rendered page
router.use('^/$', serverRenderer);
// other static resources should just be served as they are
router.use(express.static(
    path.resolve(__dirname, '..', 'build'),
    { maxAge: '30d' },
));
// tell the app to use the above rules
app.use(router);
// start the app
app.listen(PORT, (error) => {
    if (error) {
        return console.log('something bad happened', error);
    }

    console.log("listening on " + PORT + "...");
});
```

While running the command

```
node bootstrap.js
```

I am getting error that

> Error: Using `babel-preset-react-app` requires that you specify `NODE_ENV` or `BABEL_ENV` environment variables. Valid values are "development", "test", and "production".

Comment: **See Also**: [babel-preset-react-app not picking up environment variables](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44198100/1366033)

Answer (score 17):

There are a few options here. I will describe the most easy options.

The most easy one is to run your node bootstrap.js like this:

```
NODE_ENV=production BABEL_ENV=production node bootstrap.js
```

But that is just too long to remember every time, so you can use package.json scripts.

If you open up your package.json file, you should see a scripts section (if not, [see the doc](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts)). In that scripts section you can create your own scripts.

I mostly use 2 scripts, one for development and one for production. So in your case something like:

```
"scripts": {
   "start": "NODE_ENV=development BABEL_ENV=development node bootstrap.js",
   "serve": "NODE_ENV=production BABEL_ENV=production node bootstrap.js"
}
```

Now you can run your node app like this:

In development

`node run start` or `node start` (because node start is an alias for node run start)

and in production

`node run serve` (no shorthands here)

If you still think your package.json becomes too large, you can abstract that away to some .js files. And change your scripts accordingly to something like:

```
"scripts": {
   "start": "node scripts/start.js"
   "serve": "node scripts/serve.js"
}
```

In those script files you can define both of those environment variables before running your app.

Comment: In both cases, I am getting the error  'NODE_ENV' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: ooh, you are using windows I guess? Then you either should SET those environments first per environment like `SET NODE_ENV=development & BABEL_ENV=development`, next you should be able to run `node bootstrap.js`. But the best way is to abstract those variables directly to that start.js file. By either doing it manually or with the dotenv package. With the dotenv package you can create a .env file to store those environment variables. But that's not a best practice for the `NODE_ENV` and `BABEL_ENV` variables.

Comment: what do you think the best way is? and start.js file? you mean where i will store the scripts?

Comment: yes. You create a start.js file in which you set the NODE_ENV and BABEL_ENV environments, next you require your bootstrap.js in your start.js with `require('./bootstrap.js')`. But set the environment variables BEFORE you require the bootstrap.js. 
The reason you don't add it to your bootstrap.js is because of `deveopment`, `test` and `production` states. React will disable debuggin etc. in production mode.

Comment: process.env.NODE_ENV = "development";
process.env.BABEL_ENV="development";

require('./bootstrap');

Comment: using this, gives another error. Options {"loose":true} passed to C:\Users\abhi\Desktop\Do-it-App\do-it-app\node_modules\babel-preset-env\lib\index.js which does not
accept options.

Comment: Just remove the line `ignore:[/(node-modules)/],` from your bootstrap.js. Because babel-register will auto-ignore your node-modules folder. If you want to ignore more specific, [read the docs](https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/babel-register/) about babel-register.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170449/discussion-between-abhishek-kulshrestha-and-leroy).

Answer (score 12):

For solving the next error

```
0:0  error  Parsing error: [BABEL] {some-path}: Using `babel-preset-react-app` requires that you specify `NODE_ENV` or `BABEL_ENV` environment variables. Valid values are "development", "test", and "production". Instead, received: undefined. (While processing: "{project-path}\\node_modules\\babel-preset-react-app\\index.js")
```

It was useful for me to add

```
"parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
```

into "eslintConfig" block in the package.json of my React app.

Answer (score 6):

## Error: Using babel-preset-react-app requires that you specify NODE_ENV or BABEL_ENV

##### Answer for CRA(create react app):

@origin post https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/2377

### #Error:

```
0:0  error  Parsing error: [BABEL] {some-path}: Using `babel-preset-react-app` requires 
that you specify `NODE_ENV` or `BABEL_ENV` environment variables. Valid values are "development", "test", and "production". Instead, received: undefined. (While processing: "{project-path}\\node_modules\\babel-preset-react-app\\index.js")
```

### #Description:

Problem occured after added **.babelrc** file to CRA using **@rescripts/cli** and **@rescripts/rescript-use-babel-config**.

### For fix error you should:

#### Typescript:

Added **"parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",** to your eslint.

#### Javascript:

Added **"parser": "@babel/eslint-parser",** to your eslint.

Eslint docs: https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring/plugins#specifying-parser

### Example of typescript eslint config in package.json for CRA:

```
"eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest",
      "eslint:recommended"
    ],
    "globals": {
      "NodeJS": true
    },
    "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
    "overrides": [
        {
            "files": ["*.ts", "*.tsx"],
            "rules": {
                "no-undef": "off",
                "no-unused-vars": "off",
                "@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars": ["error"]
            }
        }
    ],
    "rules": {
      "no-empty": [
        "error",
        {
          "allowEmptyCatch": true
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31927679)

Answer (score 0):

add following to your .eslintrc file. it worked for me

```js
parserOptions: {
    babelOptions: {
      presets: [
        ['babel-preset-react-app', false],
        'babel-preset-react-app/prod'
      ]
    }
  },
```